# How can I make a polymorphic method with different signatures

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

Consider I have some **abstract** `Vehicle` class and car, truck, motorcycle abstract classes which derive from `Vehicle`. Also imagine that I have to be able to create a fueled based car or electric based car and so on for truck and motorcycle as well. (concrete classes)

Two questions:

1.Consider that I want to fill up energy in a vehicle without knowing what it is, in a polymorphic way. For example if the vehicle is fuel based I want to fill it with fuel and the method should be with 3 parameters:
 `void FillUpEnergy(EfuelType i_fuelType,int amounOfEnergy, int maxAmountOfEnergy)`

but for electricy based vehicle I need almost the same function signture but this time without fuel type of course, for example (2 parameters):

```
void FillUpEnergy(int amounOfEnergy, int maxAmountOfEnergy)
```

Can I do a polymorhic `FillUpEnergy` method with the above constraints?  (different method's signatures)

2.In my implementation all the concrete classes hold a reference for `Engine`(another abstract class) which represent a `FuelEngine` or `ElectricEngine` (other concrete classes I have which derive from Engine). For example I have a concrete class named `ElectricCar` which holds a reference for `ElectricEngine`.
Is this architecture good enough or are there better ways to implement a garage system?
(In terms of Object oriented design etc..)

Comment: I don't quite get 1) As for 2), it's called Bridge and it's one of design patterns.

Comment: Bridge pattern was my first thought as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot make a polymorphic "push-style" method with different signatures, but you can make a polymorphic "pull-style" method using the well-publicized [*Visitor Pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

The idea is to invert the sequence of interaction, and let the car object decide what to do: Instead of calling `FillUpEnergy` and *giving* the car what you think it needs, call `FillUpEnergy` and let the car *take* what it knows it needs, like this:

```
interface IEnergyProvider {
    void TakeFuel(EfuelType i_fuelType, int amounOfEnergy);
    void TakeElectricity(int amounOfEnergy);
}
interface ICar {
    void FillUpEnergy(IEnergyProvider provider);
}
```

Now the signature of your polymorphic method is fixed, but the dispatch of the method takes two legs instead of one:

- You call `myCar.FillUpEnergy(myProvider)`
- The car calls `myProvider.TakeFuel` or `myProvider.TakeElectricity`

Comment: nice answer! Miss the old avatar though

Comment: but isn't visitor here unecessary complex? Regarding that taking electricity and taking any other kind of fuel sounds like the same concept...

Comment: @Sebastian You are absolutely right about the visitor pattern: it can easily get out of hand, especially if you need to maintain extensibility. But in cases of hierarchies that could be specified upfront, such as this one, it shouldn't be a big deal: with only a handful of methods, walking through the interactions in your mind remains easy. As far as fueling with gas and electric being the same concept, I think the design reflects that by providing a single `FillUpEnergy` method.

Answer (score 4):

Regarding question 1)

You could make electric/gasoline part of the fueltype and handle this in your domain logic.

C# does not offer polymorphism with different signatures.

2) is called Composition

Answer (score 2):

What distinguishes the `ElectricCar` from the `FueledCar`? Nothing but the engine (conceptually):

```
interface IEngine
{
    void FillUpFuel(int amountOfFuel, int maxAmountOfFuel);
}

class ElectricEngine : IEngine
{
    public void FillUpFuel(int amountOfFuel, int maxAmountOfFuel) { ... }
}

abstract class Vehicle
{
    public abstract IEngine Engine { get; }
}

class Car : Vehicle
{
    public IEngine _engine;
    public override IEngine Engine { get { return _engine; } }

    public Car(IEngine engine)
    {
        _engine = engine;
    }
}
...
var electricCar = new Car(new ElectricEngine());
electricCar.Engine.FillUpFuel(40, 70);
```

Typical composition vs inheritance example. Naming is a bit odd with ElectricEngine filling up fuel... but that's not the point.

Comment: In this case Car is the aggregate root. As Law of Demeter states you should never access Engine separately, only via Car object. Incapsulation is totally broken here.

Answer (score 0):

About 1)
The point of having `FillUpEnergy` polymorphic ([subtype polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtype_polymorphism)) is to be able to call this method when the only thing you know is that the object is a `Vehicle`.

If you need to know the exact type in order to choose the correct set of argument, then their is no need for this function to be polymorphic.

About 2)
Nothing's shocking

Answer (score -1):

1. You can't do that, because it would be exactly a violation of encapsulation.
2. I don't understand your question regarding engines, but I can surely say that there could be a lot of better ways to implement "garage system" just because there are so many different "garage systems". Which in fact means that you should not try to model your system (in terms of OOP or any other terms) until you get a good grasp of your requirements.